# How to write post method in angular and c#?

Tags: c#, angular

Hi I want to write a `post` method so I can add new data in my database. 
I know how to write `get` but I don't know how to write  post 
this is my code for `get` in angular:

```
 constructor(private customerService: CustomerService) {
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.customerService.getCustomers()
            .subscribe((data) => {
                console.log(data);
                this.customers = data;
            })
    }
```

and this is my backend code:

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
    public class CustomerController: ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ICustomerService _service;

        public CustomerController(ICustomerService service)
        {
            _service = service;

        }

        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [Route("api/customer/getcustomer")]
        public Task<List<CustomerDto>> GetCustomer()
        {
            return _service.GetCustomer();
        }
```

How can I write `post` in c# and angular??

Comment: Use HttpPost instead of HttpGet  (obviously), create a class file modeling your body and add it as [FromBody] parameter of C# function (will be "null" if it doesn't match the fields). In Angular, nearly the same thing, except in the service, you use http.post instead of http.get, and give the payload as an additional parameter

Answer (score 1):

```
    // POST Customer Create A New Customer
    [HttpPost("CustomerDto")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<CustomerDto >> Post([FromBody] CustomerDto 
                                                               customer)
    {

        Customer trueorfalse =await  
                             CustomerServices.GetCustomerByEmail(Customer.Email);

        if (trueorfalse!=null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("email", "Customer email already in use");
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        try
        {
            if (Customer== null)
            {
                _logger.LogError("Customer object sent from client is null.");
                return BadRequest("Customer object is null");
            }
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _logger.LogError("Invalid Customer object sent from client.");
                 return BadRequest("Invalid model object");
            }

            Customer result = await CustomerServices.SaveCustomer(Customer);
            Customer e = new Customer();
            
            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetCustomer),new { id = result.CustomerId}, result);
            


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            _logger.LogError($"Something went wrong inside Customer action: 
              {ex.Message}");
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
           
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
//only use frombody if you are planning on sending something from your body. 
public HttpResponseMessage tmpName([FromBody]MyClass myClass)
{
   //write code here 
   return new HttpResponseMessage((HttpStatusCode)200);
}
```

Comment: Whatever you want the request to do @nazanin77

Answer (score 0):

You 'll need something like this. But I think you could manage without asking with some research.

C#

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/customer/createCustomer")]
[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.Created)]
[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Example([FromBody]CustomerDto customer)
{
    //do smth
    return Created();
}
```

Angular:

```
 this.post<ICreateCustomer, ICustomerr>(this.api.url("customer"),
        Customer,
        errorParams,
        (u) => ({
            ...customer
            ]
        }));
```